# Razor - Type of conditional expression cannot be determined

Tags: razor

I'm having an issue with conditional expression. Here is my code:

```
<td>@((test) ? '-' : "No")</td>
```

The error is:

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'char' and 'string'.

Comment: The final part of your error message was all you needed.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I've found the solution.

because the first part of my condition is `'-'` as a char, and my second condition as a string, this is what causes the error.

So I change my code for this:

```
<td>@((test) ? "-" : "No")</td>
```